# ON EXCEL mac when ever i put the = sign the formula bar in the cell doesn't come up anymore and provide me options as to selecting formulas?

Tags: excel, formula

On excel mac I used to be able to enter a formula and =CO and a list of formulas would come up such as COUNT, COUNTA, COUNTIF would list essentially within the cell. I seem to have lost that formatting for some reason. I tried a bunch of places to find this online but having no luck? anyone had this problem before?

Comment: This should be asked at SuperUser.com

Answer (score -1):

In Office 2007 for Windows, this setting is in Options > Formulas > Working with formulas > Formula AutoComplete.